# Adjust resolution of Mac OS X in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, macos-sierra

I am using virtual box in  Ubuntu `16.04LTS` (host). I have installed `Mac Os Sierra` in virtual box. But I can't get the full resolution . How can I fix this?

Comment: We consider questions about Hackintoshes off topic. Running macOS in a VM under a non-macOS host environment is *not* supported and against the macOS license agreement, so things are expected not to work.

Comment: Meta:[Are hackintosh questions allowed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)

Answer (score 1):

In VNC I use an app called '[Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12)'. It changes the resolution up to 1920x1080.